# Quran, Mutawatir?

Tags: reference-request, uloom-al-quran

As it is commonly said that "Quran is mutawatir".

### Question:

I just want to know, is there anyone from the Salaf who has said "Quran is mutawatir" ?? I mean, the word "Mutawatir" was used by anyone in the first 3 generations of Islam?

Please notice, I am not saying to prove to me how Quran is mutawatir! If there was someone who said it, just give me authentic evidence! If not, please tell me, "no, there was none".

Thank You.

Comment: Qur'an doubtlessly is mutwatir. What is a matter of discussion is whether the qira'at are mutwatir.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I know that, brother... But I am not asking whether Quran or Quranic Qiraats are mutawatir or not... I just want to know whether anyone from the Salaf has said "Quran is Mutawatir" or the word "Mutawatir" was used for Quran.

Comment: Terms like "mutawatir" "aahaad" etc. are simply technical lingo to describe the reality of things. Most of those terms didn't exist in the time of the Sahabah. That doesn't mean the Sahabah didn't think the Quran was mutawatir; it means they didn't use those terms.

Comment: @TheZ You said "That doesn't mean the Sahabah didn't think the Quran was Mutawatir"... Where is the proof of this?